# How to text search library source in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, ide, full-text-search

From within Netbeans, is it possible to perform a full text search upon the source jars associated with the project library jars? If it's not possible from within the IDE, does there exists some other tools which would allow this?

Comment: Are you looking for a class that exists in one of the jars?

Comment: @Jonathon: No, that is easy enough with the "Go To Source" context menu. I would like to search for all references to a class. But sometimes I just want to find any generic text, for example, within the comments

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are just zip files in disguise, so any tool that will search or index zip files without exploding them would do.

Sort of that, you could just explode them into a directory and search with whatever you like. e.g. find, xargs and grep.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I have been searching to date. But it's a bit laborious and you have to unzip all of the sources jars and I have quite a few of them.